# How do I replace the OOTB woo customer completed order email?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation, woocommerce-email

In a plugin I'm working on, I'm trying to replace the OOTB customer-completed-order email with a template in the plugin

Constructor:

```
define( 'BKF_WC_EMAIL_PATH', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
add_filter('wc_get_template', array($this, 'bkf_customer_completed_order_template'), PHP_INT_MAX, 5);
```

Function:

```
    function bkf_customer_completed_order_template($template, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path) {
        if( $template_name == 'emails/customer-completed-order.php' ) {
            $template = trailingslashit(BKF_WC_EMAIL_PATH) . 'templates/' . $template_name;
            return $template;
        }
    }
```

[note the template is still pulling the default woo one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADQRq.png)

Any thoughts/ideas are welcome!

Comment: I am unsure if you have debugging ON or not, but you should get an error from that code as the `woocommerce_locate_template` filter hook returns only 3 params and you have defined `$accepted_args` as **4**, Please fix this thing and enable debugging and look for errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Have fixed the number of args - no change in the outcome there unfortunately.
I've been running it with debug and it's not showing anything other than "CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH is already defined" at the line where i define it

Comment: So, whether I use the deprecated `woocommerce_locate_template` or the current `wc_get_template` filter, I've tried adding `error_log('Hello world!');` outside of the `if()` statement but nothing is getting logged when I load the template's settings page and/or view the template on that page - implying to me that the filter is not firing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out!

Instead of the method used in my original question, here's what worked for me:

I created a new class (similar to woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php) - for demo purposes we'll call it `My_Custom_Class`

I then called like so in my constructor for the parent class I was working on:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_classes', array( $this, 'bk_register_email' ), PHP_INT_MAX, 1 );
```

And added this function:

```
public function bk_register_email( $emails ) {
        require_once 'emails/my-custom-class.php';

        $emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'] = new My_Custom_Class();

        return $emails;
    }
```